# in setOnClickListeners (Kotlin), what is the different between { it } and { view: View -> view... }?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, navigation, fragment

in setOnClickListeners (Kotlin), what is the different between { it } and { view: View -> view... } ?

 I tried both, and both works. So I was wondering what is the different?. is it okay if I use {it} always?, because it is easier for me to remember.
And what is the use of -> symbol ?

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
        }
```

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax

Comment: Yes both are same as it is using lamda function feature in kotlin , we can avoid parentheses if have one one parameter.checkout this for understanding :
https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a lambda has only one parameter it is exposed as `it` by default. You can choose to give it an explicit name with the syntax: `{ name -> }`.